# Hide element with JQuery and activate button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I am making a product with 3 variables. A customer can pickup the products at our place, or we can deliver the products. Because of practical things, we choose to sell products there should be delivered as packages with 30, 60 or 90 products in.

Before a price can be shown, all 3 variables need to get selected. So here comes the problem. If a person wants to pickup the products at our place only 2 variables need to be selected: Length in m and Pickup or Delivery. But that will not give a price. Therefore I need to insert "Pickup" in "Packages" again to get a price.

But I would like to hide "pickup" in packages, so I do not confuse the visitor to much. The image describes what I am looking for:

[image]

The page can [be seen here][2]

This is the code I have until now, but as I see it either my code is not executed or the code is simply wrong. The page is looking excact the same as before I added my code to functions.php, and none of the functions are executed.

Based on my description does anybody have a good idea to what is wrong with my code?

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_packages">
    <li data-wvstooltip="pickup" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-pickup" title="pickup" data-value="pickup">
        <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">pickup</span>
    </li>
</ul>

<ul class="variable-items-wrapper button-variable-wrapper" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_packages">
    <li data-wvstooltip="pickup" class="variable-item button-variable-item button-variable-item-pickup selected" title="pickup" data-value="pickup">
        <span class="variable-item-span variable-item-span-button">pickup</span></li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**PHP and script:**

```
function custom_script_name(){
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_pickup-og-delivery] li").click(function(){
        var selectedDelivery = jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_pickup-og-delivery]").find("li.selected").attr("data-value");
        if (selectedDelivery == "pickup"){
            jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup] span").click();
            jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup]").hide(); // hide the "pickup" option in "Packages" if you like
        }
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'custom_script_name');
```

Comment: it is easy if you give drop down for pickup and delivery and based on selection of that you can show further option.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need to keep it as buttons because the customer with for that. There is no conditional logicin Wordpress. Then  you need to buy Gravity forms etc, which the client do not want to. Therefore I am trying my best to find an alternative solution :-)

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @stefo91. I am sorry if I was not clear enough. I just updated my question again, i hope it is more clear.

Comment: You can add display: none to packages pickup or add a css class to them that has display: none; Then check through jquery if someone hits pickup from "pickup on delivery" to show the pickup from packages

Comment: Thank you for your comment @IndF.Ashiku. It is correct with the `display: none;`. But the pickup still needs to be selected to get a price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below code it will hide the button but on click pickup, it is selected. just update the jquery and try once. hope it was work

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup]").hide();
    jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_pickup-og-delivery] li").click(function(){
        var selectedDelivery = jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_pickup-og-delivery]").find("li.selected").attr("data-value");
        if (selectedDelivery == "pickup"){
            jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup] span").click();
            jQuery("ul[data-attribute_name=attribute_pa_packages] li[data-value=pickup]").hide(); // hide the "pickup" option in "Packages" if you like
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer Alfaraz. I just tried to update the functions.php with your code, but can see it is not doing anything. The code I added is this: https://paiza.io/projects/yCxqHpYXRidzwHiAyd1yDQ. DO you have an idea why that is? If you got access to my Wordpress, could you then better help me? Best regards.

Comment: Yes, i will help you if you give me wordpress site access.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Where can I send the login details for you?

Comment: You can send me here, or if you want to send it over on Skype. ?

Comment: Please write here when you wrote down the code, so I can delete the comment again. It is a testsite before I push to live

Comment: Ok login details working.. let me check the code.

You just want to hide element of pickup when user visit and once pickup button clicked then below pickup button selected but it remain hide. right ?

Comment: Yes but the pickup here should never be shown to the visitor: https://pasteboard.co/Ih5bAM3.png, but always be active unless "Delivery" is clicked.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194168/discussion-between-alfaraz-shaikh-and-julie24).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand the question properly, You do not need the secomd pickup button. All you need to do is to play around on when to show the price. Whenever the length, pickup or delivery or packages button is clicked, check if all the required conditions are met to show the price, then show the price. The check could be like, if delivery is selected, then packages should also be selected, else, if pickup is selected, packages is not required.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Yes that is true. I am more looking for some code suggestions, or what there is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correct:

- you wanna hide the PickUp button in "Pickup or Delivery" on page load
- Show the Pickup button in "Packages" when User clicks Pickup from "Pickup or Delivery".

Here's a JS way of doing it:

- **Disable** the Pickup button in "Packages" on **page load**.
- **Enable** Pickup button in "Packages" when user clicks on **Pickup** button in "Pickup or Delivery"
- **Disable** Pickup button in "Packages" when user clicks on **Delivery** button in "Pickup or Delivery"

Here's a sample codewith simpler HTML(Live stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-l9ddiq):

```
<div>
  <span>Length</span>
  <button>4.2m</button>
  <button>5.1m</buton>
</div>

<div>
  <span>Pickup or delivery</span>
  <button id="pickup-button">Pickup</button>
  <button id="delivery-button">Delivery</buton>
</div>

<div id="packages">
  <span>Packages</span>
  <button class="toggle-button" style="display: none;">Pickup</button>
  <button>30</button>
  <button>60</button>
  <button>90</button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const pickUpButton = document.getElementById('pickup-button');
pickUpButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const packageButtons = document.querySelector('#packages').querySelectorAll('button');
  packageButtons.forEach(button => {
    if (button.classList.contains('toggle-button')) {
      button.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      button.disabled = true;
    }
  });
});

const deliveryButton = document.getElementById('delivery-button');
deliveryButton.addEventListener('click', event => {
  const packageButtons = document.querySelector('#packages').querySelectorAll('button');
  packageButtons.forEach(button => {
    if (button.classList.contains('toggle-button')) {
      button.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      button.disabled = false;
    }
  });
});
```

[image: ed]